# Removing entire tags containing a specific term using regex

Tags: regex, phpmyadmin, sublimetext3

I am altering a database with approximately 500 html pages using phpmyadmin.
Several pages contain a Facebook Pixel or Google Tag that I would like to remove.

The easiest way I thought would be to search via regex the entire tag that contains some expression or term related to Facebook or Google, and replace it with blank.

An example would be

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXX');
  </script>
```

or

```html
<script>
    (window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '9999999999999999');
    fbq('track', 'salespage_xxxxxx');
  </script>
```

Although all are unique, some have the same code or another element that makes it possible to identify each one of them.

Before running in myphpadmin, I'm trying to formulate the expression using SublimeText3

It's the first contact I have with the regex and I found it fascinating, but even following some references I can't match the search.

The expression I came up with after some research was

```
<(.*)>[\s\S]face[\s\S]<\/(.*)>
```

Where I thought the expression would select the entire tag containing the word "face", but it doesn't find anything.

I would like some help.

If it works, it would be able to make several other necessary changes.

Comment: You might want to refine your question a bit; "face" doesn't appear at all in your first example, so it's hard to tell what you want to match against. Also, the `.*` at the beginning of your expression is a "greedy" operator that will match all the way to the end of the line, and the `[\s\S]` construction doesn't make much sense because it means "match one whitespace OR one non-whitespace character", which would of course match anything.

(Manually parsing HTML is tricky, and custom regexes usually miss something.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment.
When I refer to "face", it can be any other term that is inside the tag. In this case it was "face" (facebook.com) because it was included in the script link. As sometimes both face and google scripts have variations, it could be any other term here.

I don't need something perfect. I just need to remove some unwanted functions.

Comment: As for the regex, my thought was as follows:
`[\s\S]face[\s\S]`: Will use the term "face" as a basis for locating the start of the match. Here it would match all the text before and after "face".
`<(.*)> `: Would select any tag and all its content, be it <script>, <div>, <a>.
`<\/(.*)>`: the closing of the tag indicating the end of the selection.
Does that make any sense?

Comment: (1) As I mentioned above, `[\s\S]` means "match any whitespace or non-whitespace character", and is basically the equivalent of `.`. The `*` in your `.*` means "grab as much as possible", so it would eat any nested tags as well, which probably isn't what you want. It would match all of `<foo blah blah>some <stuff> and <more stuff> </and> </all> </the> </way> </to> </HERE>`. Parsing HTML with regular expressions is actually very complicated beyond the simplest basics, and you're probably better off using an actual parser library if you want something robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex expression will match the `<script>` tag that contains the `face` keyword

```
<(script)>(?:(?!<\/\1>|face)[\s\S])+face(?:(?!<\/\1>)[\s\S])+<\/\1>
```

See example: https://regex101.com/r/LfRlBV/1

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.
For real, this is waaay more complex than i thought. But i really appreciate the direction you gave me. Many thanks